# How to combine multiple field from another table into a single field in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, field

I have to record hourly temperature from 8am-5pm everyday. I made a form as below, however by this form I had to record each data into its own field.

I then made a new table consisting of only the hourly average hourly temperature. Here comes the tough part, I can't seem to find a way to plot a graph (avg temp over time) since they are in different field. So I figured I have to make a new field consisting of the time of day and to combine those field (hourly avg temp field) into a single field named "AVG_TEMP".
The question is, how do I do this?
I have tried :

```
INSERT INTO temp_avg [(AVG_Temp)] 
SELECT ([temp avg].[AVG_AM_8]), ([temp avg].[AVG_AM_9]), ([temp avg].[AVG_AM_10]), ([temp avg].[AVG_AM_11]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_12]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_1]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_2]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_3]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_4]), ([temp avg].[AVG_PM_5])
FROM [temp_avg];
```

[IMAGE 1 : FORM to record data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAPH5.png)

I need to make the combine fields from the above into the below illustration :
[Illustration of changes need to be made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIAH1.png)

----------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------

In short, I have to plot a graph based on the below data, How do I plot a graph when the data is in different column(field)?

```
|8 AM | 9 AM | 10 AM | 11 AM | 12 PM | 1 PM | 2 PM | 3 PM | 4 PM | 5 PM | 
| 20  |  30  |  20   |   23  |   24  |  23  |  21  |  23  |  22  |  20  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `union all`...

```
select 8 as HOUR_AVG, AVG_AM_8 from temp_avg
union all
select 9 as HOUR_AVG, AVG_AM_9 from temp_avg
union all
...
select 17 as HOUR_AVG, AVG_PM_5 from temp_avg
```

However, I don't think this is likely the best way to design this sort of reporting.  For better ways, we would need to know more about your schema. (In other words, there is probably a simpler way to get this information if the entire table schema was known.)

Comment: I have to plot a graph based on the table that I included under edited section of the original question. Do you think we have a way of plotting graph without sorting it into only 2 field (time vs temperature)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "plot".  Surely, you can plot a graph using Excel or Google with two columns.  You should post the schema of the table(s) if you want more in-depth answers.